# android buttons and how they work

Tags: java, android, onclick, android-button

I know how to disable button to prevent it from being clicked twice.  However if i want to enable it again as soon as its safe can i do something like this where i call setenabled(true) in the onclick?? Is the button disabled as soon as setenabled(false) is called or does it only disable when the onclick function is finished?

```
   button.setOnclickListener(new View.onClickListener(){

          public void onClick(View v) {
                button.setEnabled(false);
                /// do stuff
                button.setEnabled(true);
          }
    });
```

Comment: Yes. you can do that thing. Instead of "button" use "v" ( View v ). Override function return view which is clicked.

Comment: you want your button to clicked once or twise

Answer (score 3):

Why not make it simpler?

Use a `boolean` as a flag to check when the process is running. And if it is running, don't run it till the earlier process doesn't complete.

The code example below will ensure that when the task is running, the `onClickListener()` will simply not trigger. No need to worry about disabling and then enabling it again.

**EDIT:**

After a prolonged discussion (in the comments), with [**Zabri**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1274911/zabri). Just for kicks, I tried out the solution I originally posted. And as it turns out, he was **right** after all. :-(

I wrong in the initial solution (which was untested, but *boo hoo* to me). So time to suck up and post a working and **tested** solution.

Full props to **Zabri** for pointing out the obvious flaw in the code. :-)

For example (TESTED CODE):

```
boolean taskRunning = false;
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (taskRunning == false) {

            // TOGGLE THE boolean HERE TO INDICATE RUNNING
            taskRunning = true;

            // / do stuff

            // TOGGLE THE boolean HERE TO INDICATE TASK COMPLETED
            taskRunning = false;

        }

    }
});
```

*As mentioned, this is untested code. I just typed it out here.*

Comment: Yeah, this one is much simpler solution.

Comment: Not only is this not a simpler solution, I don't even think it will work. The `taskRunning` is _false_ at the beginning. So the `OnClickListener` gets set to the `button`. When the `button` gets clicked, what prevents it from being clicked on again? The `OnClickListener` is still set. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Also, instead of writing `if (something == true)`, you can just write `if (something)`.

Comment: @Zabri: Well, basically, when the `taskRunning` is running `(taskRunning == true)`, the `if...else` will never reach the `OnClickListener()` for it to trigger.

Comment: @Zabri: True. It can be written that way. But this is my coding convention. Nothing says, I can't write it like that eh? ;-) The logic, regardless of how you code it, is still valid. Feel free to try it and see if it works.

Comment: @IceMAN: What will not get triggered? Setting an `OnClickListener` again? Once you set an `OnClickListener` to a `View` (or `Button` in this case), it's just set. You'd need to move the `if (taskRunning)` inside the `onClick()` method for this to work.

Comment: @Zabri: One, Use the code and see if it works. And two, _Setting an OnClickListener again?_: Where in the post does it say that? In the post, I say: _will simply not trigger_. And if you disagree, you have enough rep to show your disagreement with a downvote. I stand by the logic I have demonstrated as an example in my post! Moving the `if....else` in the `OnClickListener()` will produce, essentially, the same result. In my code, I reiterate, the `OnClickListener()` will **not** trigger.

Comment: @IceMan: You take a `View` and set an `OnClickListener` to it with the method `View.setOnClickListener(OnClickListener)`. Then the `OnClickListener` is set and the `View` remembers it. And whatever's inside the `onClick()` method of the set `OnClickListener` will happen everytime the `View` is clicked. Unless you disable the `View` or set the `OnClickListener` to something else (like `null` for example). I might be wrong (hence no downvote), but I am pretty sure that this is how it works. I rest my case.

Comment: @Zabri: You know what. Time for me to man up and admit. You were **right**. I was **wrong**. I am updating the post with code I have tested. Thanks a ton. ;-) Now you can exercise your downvote. I did ask for it anyway. :-)